# Implementing function to reverse the order of elements in a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, reverse

I am trying to implement my own version of the reverse function in Haskell. The following code utilizing the : operator.

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' [] = []
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs : [x]
```

This results in the a compilation error. However, if I use the ++ operator instead, the code compiles without issue. This is demonstrated here:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]
reverse' [] = []
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

Why doesn't  the : operator work here?

Comment: Look at the type of `(:)`.

Comment: Bear in mind that adding a value to the front of a list with `:` is cheap, while concatenating two lists with `++` is _not_. Doing `++` many times is not ideal from a performance standpoint.

Comment: And just for fun: `reverse' = foldl (flip (:)) []`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` is used to add an element to list, so the first (left) operand should be an element (`a`) but you have `[a]` hence the type mismatch. `++` joins to lists (result of `reverse' xs` is of type `[a]` and `[x]` is of type `[a]`).

From "Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!" [An intro to lists](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#an-intro-to-lists) paragraph:

> A common task is putting two lists together. This is done by using the `++` operator.

> putting something at the beginning of a list using the `:` operator (also called the cons operator)

> Notice how `:` takes a number and a list of numbers or a character and a list of characters, whereas `++` takes two lists. Even if you're adding an element to the end of a list with `++`, you have to surround it with square brackets so it becomes a list.